# Java Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

What's the difference between a JdbcTemplate object and a SimpleJdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html), `SimpleJdbcTemplate` is a

> Java-5-based convenience wrapper for the classic Spring `JdbcTemplate`, taking advantage of varargs and autoboxing, and exposing only the most commonly required operations in order to simplify `JdbcTemplate` usage.

In other words, `SimpleJdbcTemplate` just breaks the "regular" `JdbcTemplate` down to the most common/convenient parts — in other words, it simplifies it.

Comment: Thanks Torgamus. I'll use the SimpleJdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 18):

As of [Spring 3.1 `SimpleJdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html) has been deprecated, and most of the features of `SimpleJdbcTemplate` have been integrated into [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html), except named parameter which is provided by [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).

The bottom line is, if you're using SimpleJdbcTemplate is perfectly fine, and there is no rush to upgrade, but for new developments, you should use JdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

If anyone's interested, [I've posted an usage example of JdbcTemplate](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=1261) in my blog (starting form the [project set up in the previous post](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=1252)), more interesting examples are in the [official Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples).