# JdbcTemplate and SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring 3.0 . For DAO access i have choosen SpringJDBC. SpringJDBC provides JDBC Template and SimpleJDBCTemplate . Which one is best. I read in some of the forum SimpleJDBCTemplate going to be deprecated in Spring 3.1. What is the difference between these two.Guide me which one is best.

Answer (score 34):

In Spring 3.x you should use `JdbcTemplate`.

In previous versions of Spring `SimpleJdbcTemplate` leveraged new features of Java 5, whereas `JdbcTemplate` maintained compatibility with pre-Java 5 environments. But now all features of `SimpleJdbcTemplate` have been added to `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: It's not the only difference - `SimpleJdbcTemplate` supports named parameters like in `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but `JdbcTemplate` only supports `?` style parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot.The query we are using is whether DB specific in SpringJDBC or SpringJDBC provides any option that our query will run in any kind of DB like Hibernate provides HQL.(Now i am using SQL DB in future i might go with oracle , So the same will run in oracle or needs any change in future)

Comment: No, spring HSBC doesn't provide any abstraction over SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In spring 4.1.3, SimpleJdbcTemplate is deprecated and it has been completely removed in 4.3.3

Comment: Deprecated in Spring 3.1 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365359/java-spring-jdbctemplate